# How could we state that $A$ and $B$ are compact if $A\times B$ is compact in $M \times N$?

Tags: compactness

Assume that the Cartesian product of two non-empty sets $A \subseteq M$
and $B\subseteq N$ is compact in $M \times N$. Which steps should I follow to prove  that $A$ and $B$ are compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking if whether $A\times B$ compact implies $A$ (and $B$) is compact. Note that $\pi:A\times B\to A$ defined by $\pi:(a,b)\mapsto a$
is continuous and surjective...

Comment: You beat me on time ;)

Comment: sorry could you explain with more detail?

Comment: @muratyilmaz use the result "continuous image of compact set is compact